How to resolve version conflicts in a Go project due to dependencies on different versions of the controller-runtime lib?
I am developing a Kubernetes tool that depends on different versions of the controller-runtime library. Specifically, my tool directly calls the API types of mysql-operator to create resources, uses the API types of chaos-mesh-operator to create faults, and also calls the Kubernetes API to fetch Pods and other resources. These three dependencies require different versions of the controller-runtime library, leading to version handling issues when running go mod tidy.
